# C++ Deployment - dll files

Tags: c++, eclipse, deployment

So, I've been developing Java apps for a while now, and I wanted to get into c++. Since I know eclipse quite well, I decided to go for it.

I've created a HelloWorld project to test things out, and it works well in Eclipse. But now, how do I actually deploy it? Eclipse automatically generates an executable, which works well on my system, but I tried to send it to a friend so check if it works, and it says he's missing "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll".

I'm new to this, and I really don't know what I have to do. I mean, it would feel really weird having to create a setup thing just for a Hello World, right?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So typically a dll (dynamically linked library) would need some sort of "entry points". Anyhow, what you have, seems to me is an executable (.exe) file not a dll. P.S. Microsoft Visual studio, i believe, has great free versions.